# Simplifying expression using eulers equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following expression which I've been told to simplify using Eulers equation:

$$\cos(22t)+\cos(10t)$$

I think I have to substitute these expressions in (from rewriting Eulers equation)

$$\cos(22t)+\cos(10t)=\frac{e^{i22t}+e^{-i22t}}2+\frac{e^{i10t}+e^{-i10t}}2$$

But I just have no idea where to go from here. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The assignment description specifically says to use Euler's equation.

Comment: Hint: note that the expression can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{(e^{16it}+e^{-16it})(e^{6it}+e^{-6it})}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I really don't want you guys to do my homework, but I just still can't figure out where to go from there.

Comment: Multiply top & bottom by $2$ & use Euler formula the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this expression is equal to: $$\dfrac { \left( e ^ { 16 i t } + e ^ { - 16 i t } \right) \left( e ^ { 6 i t } + e ^ { - 6 i t } \right) } { 2 }$$

Using Euler's formula again, we get:
$$\cos(22t) + \cos(10t) =\dfrac { 2\cos(16t) \cdot 2 \cos(6t) } { 2 }  = 2\cos(16t) 
 \cos(6t).$$

Comment: And then it can't be simplified any further?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, no.